# Get access rights of specific folder for actual user

Tags: c#, permissions, filesystems

I hope you can help me. I need to obtain access rights (read, write etc.) of specific folder for actual user (which started the program) or for his group (users/administrators...)

Code below working but I cannot obtain info which I want in format similar to:

C:\Windows (R+W)

or

C:\Windows (Full Control)

Thank you.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.AccessControl;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(getRights(@"C:\test"));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static string getRights(string path)
        {
            string rights = "eeeeee";
            try
            {
                DirectorySecurity dSecurity = Directory.GetAccessControl(path);
                foreach (FileSystemAccessRule rule in dSecurity.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(NTAccount)))
                {
                    rights += rule.FileSystemRights.ToString() + "\n";
                    rights += rule.IdentityReference.Value + "\n";
                    rights += "\n\n";
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                rights = "";
            }

            return rights;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got it right, you need something like this:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string path = @"C:\Windows";
        Console.WriteLine($"{path} - {getRights(path)}");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static string getRights(string path)
    {
        DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        if (!directoryInfo.Exists)
        {
            return "Directory doesn't exist";
        }
        FileSystemRights fsRights = 0;
        DirectorySecurity directorySecurity = directoryInfo.GetAccessControl();
        AuthorizationRuleCollection authRules = directorySecurity.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(NTAccount));
        WindowsIdentity currentUser = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
        WindowsPrincipal principal = new WindowsPrincipal(currentUser);

        foreach (AuthorizationRule rule in authRules)
        {
            FileSystemAccessRule fsRule = rule as FileSystemAccessRule;

            if (fsRule != null)
            {
                NTAccount ntAccount = rule.IdentityReference as NTAccount;

                if (principal.IsInRole(ntAccount.Value))
                {
                    if (fsRule.FileSystemRights > fsRights)
                    {
                        fsRights = fsRule.FileSystemRights;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        switch (fsRights)
        {
            case FileSystemRights.FullControl:
                return "Full Control";
            case FileSystemRights r when (r >= FileSystemRights.Write):
                return "Write";
            case FileSystemRights r when (r >= FileSystemRights.ReadData):
                return "Read";
            default:
                return "No rights";
        }
    }
}
```

Update:

```
public enum FileSystemRights
{
    ReadData = 1,
    ListDirectory = 1,
    WriteData = 2,
    CreateFiles = 2,
    AppendData = 4,
    CreateDirectories = 4,
    ReadExtendedAttributes = 8,
    WriteExtendedAttributes = 16,
    ExecuteFile = 32,
    Traverse = 32,
    DeleteSubdirectoriesAndFiles = 64,
    ReadAttributes = 128,
    WriteAttributes = 256,
    Write = 278,
    Delete = 65536,
    ReadPermissions = 131072,
    Read = 131209,
    ReadAndExecute = 131241,
    Modify = 197055,
    ChangePermissions = 262144,
    TakeOwnership = 524288,
    Synchronize = 1048576,
    FullControl = 2032127
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It´s work perfectly. Only one more question... Are "Full Control", "Write" and "Read" all rights, which can be? Isnt possible something like "Write, Read" without "Full control"? Or if folder have "Write", does it mean the user can "Read" too?

Comment: Your guess is right. I've updated my answer with FileSystemRights enum, that has all the rights in ascending order.

Comment: I am not sure how to use your update. I tried copy it into my code, but I get some errors. But thx again!

Comment: You don't have to copy it in your code; it's already there since is coming from `System.Security.AccessControl`. I put it here just as an in-order overview or file system rules.